# How to create bogus Predicate in JPA

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

Is there any way to create bogus Predicate in JPA?
Sort of like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder;
Predicate pred = cb.isTrue(false);
```

Almost all the methods of CriteriaBuilder take Expression as parameter.
I also tried this to no avail:

```
Expression<Object> path = cb.coalesce.value(null);
Predicate pred = cb.isNotNull(path);
```

Obviously it throws NPE, however I thought that this might work, because according to API documentation:

> A coalesce expression is equivalent to a case expression that **returns null if all its arguments evaluate to null**, and the value of its first non-null argument otherwise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think a [disjunction](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#disjunction%28%29) is what you're looking for. It's false by default, until some real predicate is `or`ed to it.

Comment: yes, disjunction seems to be just what I need. Never worked with them before. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Works like a charm in JPA 2.0 with Hibernate 4

Answer (score 9):

`dijunction` did not work for me in more complicated query in Eclipselink 2.4.

What did was `cb.isTrue(cb.literal(false))` which is as precise representation of false as one can get.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. 4 years later, and people still search for that :) Strangely enough, I tested the solution proposed by @JB Nizet on EclipseLink and it worked. But that was long time ago.